# Is it possible to access via VBA the grammatical information that MS Word must have to perform its grammar checks?

Tags: vba, ms-word, nlp

I am trying to leverage the AI used in MS Word to ascertain the part of speech of every word in a doc file. That is, for a sentence like: "The cat sat on it.", I would get something along the lines of: "The [wdDeterminer] cat[wdNoun] sat[wdVerb] on[wdPreposition] it[wdPronoun]".

I know that Word must do this internally for its grammar proofing tools to work. My question is: is it possible for a script to access this information.

Please note, I am NOT trying to run spellcheck through VBA (though this will be a trivial part of the solution). Also, I am not interested in the thesaurus module.

There are solutions outside of VBA, such as the python Lemmatization with NLTK, but I was wondering if anyone knew of a purely VBA solution. My investigations so far suggest no, but I'm hoping I've overlooked something.

Comment: That isn't available via VBA for a very simple reason. The Word object model exists simply to automate the UI. So, if certain functionality doesn't exist in the UI, it won't be in the object model either.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt That makes sense. Thanks for confirming my suspicions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Word extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that. The best what you could use are the following properties and methods:

- The [Options.CheckGrammarWithSpelling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.options.checkgrammarwithspelling) property controls whether Word checks grammar when you check spelling by using the Spelling command (Tools menu).
- The [Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.options.checkgrammarasyoutype) property marks grammatical errors, but to see them on screen, you must set the `ShowGrammaticalErrors` property to `True`.
- The [Application.CheckGrammar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.checkgrammar) method checks a string for grammatical errors. Returns a Boolean to indicate whether the string contains grammatical errors. True if the string contains no errors.
- The [Application.CheckSpelling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.checkspelling) method checks a string for spelling errors. Returns a `Boolean` to indicate whether the string contains spelling errors. `True` if the string has no spelling errors.

Comment: I was hoping to access the application’s grammatical model of my text, but it seems that’s not available. Thanks anyway.